Is there a method (using API ) to find the gitlab runners which were registered using old method(using runner registration token)
I'm working on creating a list of runners which were registered using old registration process using runner registration token.
I tried /runners but the result didn't help.
Please tell is there any other method to retrieve that data

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
